# Django: how to mock a class inside the API view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mocking, django-unittest

Title might be a little confusing.

Say I have an `APIView` with a `post` method. Inside the post method, I introduced a class that has its own method. In this case, it's a class that deals with uploading to S3, which is something I want to skip when running unittest.

```
class SomeView(APIView):
    def post(self):
        # do something here
        input1 = some_process(payload_arg1)
        input2 = some_other_process(payload_arg2)
        uploader = S3Uploader()
        s3_response = uploader.upload_with_aux_fxn(input1, input2)
        if s3_response['status_code'] == 200:
            # do something else
            return Response('Good job I did it!', status_code=200)
        else:
            return Response('noooo you're horrible!', status_code=400)
```

Real code has different function calls and responses, obviously.

Now I need to mock that `uploader` and `uploader.upload_with_aux_fxn` so I don't actually call S3. How do I mock it?

I tried in my test script

```
from some_place import S3Uploader
class SomeViewTestCase(TestCase): 
    def setUp(self):        
        self.client = APIClient()
        uploader_mock = S3Uploader()
        uploader_mock.upload_support_doc = MagicMock(return_value={'status_code': 200, 'message': 'asdasdad'}
        response = self.client.post(url, payload, format='multipart')
```

But I still triggered S3 upload (as file shows up in S3). How do I correctly mock this?

EDIT1:

My attempt to patch

```
def setUp(self):
    self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
    self.view = ViewToTest.as_view()
    self.url = reverse('some_url')


@patch('some_place.S3Uploader', FakeUploader)
def test_uplaod(self):
    payload = {'some': 'data', 'other': 'stuff'}
    request = self.factory.post(self.url, payload, format='json')
    force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
    response = self.view(request)
```

where the FakeUplaoder is

```
class FakeUplaoder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def upload_something(self, data, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        return {'status_code': 200, 'message': 'unit test', 's3_path': 
                'unit/test/path.pdf'}

    def downlaod_something(self, s3_path):
        return {'status_code': 200, 'message': '', 'body': 'some base64 
                stuff'}
```

unfortunately this is not successful. I still hit the actual class

EDIT 2:

I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 2.7, in case people need this info

Answer (score 2):

I guess the correct approach to it would be save the file within a model with FileField, and then connect Boto to handle upload in production scenario.
Take a good look at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield
and
https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#model
this approach would preserve Django default behavior, making things more testable with Django's default test client.

Comment: doesn't FileField save locally? What if I have multiple servers to process production data, what's going to happen? Can django ensure all files are accessible? (I've run into issues like this before I believe. Sometimes data saved on the server cannot be accessed because, well, it's on a different server)

Comment: No. You can set a variable to conditionally load production environment configurations.
To upload your media files to S3 set:

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
. More details at: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

Comment: but how can I do it without going through this? All I want is to mock that one class dealing with S3Upload and fake the response. It's a separate class with its own functions. It resides inside a django `APIView`. I just need to mock it. That's all

Comment: I actually can't think about a maintainable way of doing that without the Django default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [vcrpy](https://vcrpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html). It records request to external API once and then replays answer every time you run your tests. No need to manually mock anything.

Comment: is there a way to do it with just unittest? i am not allowed to add new library whenever I want.

Comment: You should stick with mocking then. IMHO, Recreating this behavior would require too much patching of boto internals, it's not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how I would mock that `S3Uploader` in an `APITestCase`.

```
from rest_framework import status
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class SomeViewTestCase(APITestCase): 

   @mock.patch("path.to.view_file.S3Uploader")
   def test_upload(self, s3_uploader_mock):
       """Test with mocked S3Uploader"""
       concrete_uploader_mock = MagicMock(**{
           "upload_with_aux_fxn__return_value": {"status_code": 200}
       })
       s3_uploader_mock.return_value = concrete_uploader_mock
       response = self.client.post(url, payload, format='multipart')
       self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
       s3_uploader_mock.assert_called_once()
       concrete_uploader_mock.upload_with_aux_fx.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: do I need to define `s3_uploader_mock` before using it in `def test_upload`?

Comment: I tried it, with change in mock.patch with actual path. Also changed the return_value to the value I want. It still hits S3 unfortunately

Comment: Nah you don't need to define it prior, after you add the `mock.patch` decorator it should include an argument in your test function which is the mocked class/object.  I'm a little surprised to hear it's still hitting S3 with this mock in place, that indicates that the `@mock.patch` is not targeting the correct object.  Would need to see more view code to diagnose why that would be happening.

Comment: You also may want to try targeting the module where you import `S3Uploader` from, e.g. `@mock.patch("path.to.s3_module.S3Uploader")`, instead of the views module.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MagicMock` like below

```py
from unittest import mock
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class SomeTestCase(TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    self.factory = APIRequestFactory()
    self.view = ViewToTest.as_view()
    self.url = reverse('some_url')


  @mock.patch.object(S3Boto3Storage, '_save', MagicMock(return_value='/tmp/somefile.png'))
  def test_uplaod(self):
    payload = {'some': 'data', 'other': 'stuff'}
    request = self.factory.post(self.url, payload, format='json')
    force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
    response = self.view(request)
```

Comment: this doesn't work. it still hits S3 and returns `Unexpected Error: Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter Body`

Comment: This error is probably due to the fact that I'm using `json` instead of `multipart`, still, the point is not to hit S3, so I shouldn't get this error at all